# Pandas - pick up rows and columns with threshold

Tags: python, pandas

How to pick up rows and columns from Pandas table with a threshold. For example, how to only get the red rows and red columns as a new pd table from the following image.

**I want to compose a maximal rectangle where all values are greater than 5.**

[image]

Comment: what are the conditions you want to set up for each columns

Comment: To only pick up rows and columns which are greater than 5 at the same time.

Comment: What's the criteria for selecting those rows? You can use dataframe.loc to filter the rows based on a criteria and then dataframe.drop columns you'll not need.

Comment: Thanks all answers. All work great. However how to not be limited for specials columns names. Because the datas could be different later. I want to compose a maximal rectangle where all values are greater than 5.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [dataframe.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to filter the rows based on a criteria and then [dataframe.drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) columns you'll not need:

```
new_df = df.loc[(df['t3'] > 5) & (df['t4'] > 5) & (df['t5'] > 5)]
new_df = new_df.drop(columns=['t1', 't2', 't6', 't7'])
```

Comment: Thanks. How to not limited for specials columns names. Because the datas could be different later. I want to compose a maximal rectangle where all values are greater than 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter rows and columns with

```
df_new = df[df[filter_column] > value]
```

Or the following to extract values from multiple columns

```
df_new = df.loc[df[filter_column] > value, [col1, col2, col3]]
```